# How do you access Facebook scope data with Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to access data requested from Facebook. Here is my code:

```
  var auth_provider_facebook = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

/// BEGIN: configure the facebook authorization provider.
  auth_provider_facebook.addScope('user_birthday');
  auth_provider_facebook.addScope('user_about_me');
  auth_provider_facebook.addScope('user_work_history');
  auth_provider_facebook.addScope('user_education_history');

 // auth_provider_facebook.addScope('user_birthday,user_about_me,user_work_history,user_education_history');

/// END: configure the facebook authorization provider.
```

I've tried one-lining it and multi-lining it, but I am still having trouble getting the data.  The documentation found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#redirect-mode) has absolutely no information on retrieving data from the scope. The documentation provided [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html) mentions a `facebook` variable as part of the result, but it's always `undefined`. There's more documentation [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/blob/master/docs/v1/providers/facebook.md) that brings up a `thirdPartyUserData` property which is also always `undefined`.

How do I go about obtaining this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you authenticate, onAuthStateChange will give you a token. This is mine with multiple account linked.

Can you find it? Are you using Firebase v3?

[image]

Comment: I still don't see how this provides access to the Facebook scope data, such as user_birthday?

Comment: It doesn't. That info are probably available making a call to the Facebook API. Firebase allow you to access email, photo, name and uid. I suggest you to read the documentation :)

Comment: I can't find any info in the docs about accessing scope data - only about adding additional permissions. I was hoping Firebase could function as a proxy to the Facebook data, so I didn't have to use the Facebook SDK myself.

Comment: I may be wrong! check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login) for more info. Handle the sign-in flow with the Firebase SDK > section 2

Comment: I figured out how to access the data with the Facebook SDK - it was actually pretty simple ;) Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm having similar issues to what you describe. Where should I get the value I use as an access token?